# Can I run old projects after updating Unity?

Tags: unity

Today I decided to upgrade unity from 5.0.0 to 5.5.0.

But before updating it, I wanted to know: Can I run/build my projects made in Unity 5.0.0 in Unity 5.5.0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The projects will need to go through an upgrade process to work in the new version of the editor. It's likely your project will convert to the new version just fine. However, there's a possibility that the project will have issues. For example, if you were using features that were made obsolete or using assets/plugins that haven't been updated.

The upgrade process will change your project configuration and you may have issues if you want to revert your editor to 5.0.0, so ensure you make a backup.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, probably late but i will make sure to create a backup before proceeding to upgrade. A last question: What if I used some Class or functions which are deprecated, like `Application.LoadLevel` (I used a lot of this in my scripts). Do I need to find and replace it from everywhere, myself?

Comment: It depends, some methods have alternatives that are replaced automatically, some have replacements that aren't automatic and must be manually replaced, and then some will have no alternative and you'll need to find some other way. Those are listed in how common they are.